# Сравнение даты/времени в powershell

Tags: дата, powershell, время

Очень нужна ваша помощь, подскажите пожалуйста, как сравнить время в powershell?

```
while($true){
 $dt = Get-Date - Format t #формат чч:мм
 if($dt > "08:30" && $dt < "17:30"){
  #Работаем!
 }
}
```

Что я не так делаю? Как правильно сравнить? Заранее всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Вроде как надо использовать "-lt" вместо "<". Больше по теме :[раз](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097125/powershell-comparing-dates)
,[два](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882831/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-powershell-get-difference-in-minutes), [три](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($true){
    $dt = Get-Date -Format t
    if (($dt -gt "08:30") -and ($dt -lt "17:30")) {
        Write-Host "Работаем"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сравнивать прямо [datetime] объекте как они есть:

```
[datetime]::Parse('17:30:00') -ge [datetime]::Now
```

А если вычесть `[datetime]` получится `[timespan]`.

Но такой цикл как в вопросе очевидно будет часами загружать процессор.
Лучше так:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds ([datetime]::Parse('17:30:00') - [datetime]::Now).TotalSeconds
```